# Restating lambdas in Coq without extensional function equality?

Tags: coq, theorem-proving

I am going over Software Foundations. There are two definitions of list reverse function given.

```
Fixpoint rev (l:natlist) : natlist :=
  match l with
    | nil => nil
    | h :: t => rev t ++ [h]
  end.
```

and a tail-recursive one:

```
Fixpoint rev_append {X} (l1 l2 : list X) : list X :=
  match l1 with
  | [] => l2
  | x :: l1' => rev_append l1' (x :: l2)
  end.

Definition tr_rev {X} (l : list X) : list X :=
  rev_append l [].
```

Here is where the problem arrives. I am asked to prove their equality, with the following theorem stated: `Lemma tr_rev_correct : ∀X, @tr_rev X = @rev X.`

This generates the following proof state:

```
1 subgoal
______________________________________(1/1)
forall X : Type, tr_rev = rev
```

However, even if I do `unfold` `tr_rev` (and / or the other two definitions), I end up with something along the lines of:

```
1 subgoal
______________________________________(1/1)
forall X : Type, (fun l : list X => rev_append l [ ]) = rev
```

But I can't do anything with this formulation (other than `intro X`).

What I would like to have is this:

`Lemma tr_rev_correct : forall (X : Type) (l : list X), tr_rev l = rev l.`

Is there a way to replace the former with the latter without involving functional extensionality? (If I didn't  want to restate the lemma that is given by the book.)

Comment: There is no way to do what you want, unless you impose some condition on the input of `rev`. You either use functional extensionality, or work with `tr_rev_correct`.

Comment: @ejgallego this is interesting - because the concept of functional extensionality hasn't been discussed in the book prior - so I find it surprising that the theorem is stated in form which is completely useless.

Comment: Actually the exercise you are talking about belongs to the section  `Functional Extensionality` and the axiom has been defined before the exercise.

Comment: @AntonTrunov oh it turns out I'm a bloody idiot! I chopped the book up a bit and made a grevious mistake... now everything makes a lot of sense! :)

Comment: @AntlerM Yeah, it is a beautiful book! Nevertheless, you've asked a good question!